# Avoiding the use of Activate and Select when working with charts (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I know that using `Activate` and `Select` in Excel VBA is not best practice.  I've seen references on how to avoid them when dealing with Ranges (example: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)).  How can I avoid them when dealing with `ChartObjects` (or anything other than Ranges, in general)?

For instance, a way to modify the maximum value on the y-axis using `Activate` and `Select` would look something like this (which works):

```
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyChart").Activate
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("MaxVal").Value
```

In order to avoid using `Activate` and `Select`, I tired to declare variables, and work with those, but that does not work:

```
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = Worksheets("Chart")
     With ws.ChartObjects("MyChart").Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = Range("MaxVal").Value
     End With
```

The code above runs (i.e. does not throw an error), but the scale on the axis does not change.  What am I missing?

---

EDIT: Got it to work with this "longwinded" version:

```
    With Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects("MyChart").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = Range("MaxVal").Value
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your question #1: *How can I avoid them when dealing with ChartObjects (or anything other than Ranges, in general)?*, the method you use is correct. Your conclusion *that does not work* is brought about by the other error.

As for your question #2: *What am I missing?*, a `ChartObject` does not have a method `Axes`.
What you called the "longwinded" version is actually **the** way to do it.

PS: The only reason I can think about for the non-working code to run with no error is an error handler that ignores the error.
I get the expected "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method".

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked:

```
        With Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects("MyChart").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
            .MaximumScale = Range("MaxVal").Value
        End With
```