# Avoiding the use of Activate in Excel VBA for Chart

Tags: vba, excel

Very new to Excel VBA here... Very similar to this post: [Avoiding the use of Activate and Select when working with charts (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479409/avoiding-the-use-of-activate-and-select-when-working-with-charts-excel), I am attempting to avoid using Activate in order to make a small change to a number of Charts in a large workbook. I am performing this task for a good number of charts, so I would like to minimize the run-time as much as possible and have heard that the select/activate functions tend to slow down macros.

My example code looks like this:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Leb!$C$2:$G$2"
```

I have attempted to replace these two lines with the following since this makes logical sense to me:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Leb!$C$2:$G$2"
```

This code causes an error when run, so I then attempted to use the WITH format shown by the post mentioned above:

```
With Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart.XValues = "=Leb!$C$2:$G$2"
End With
```

This also throws an error.

I understand that I am probably making a small, syntax error, but would anyone be able to provide any insight into what I am doing wrong? (I have never used the WITH function before, so some general insight on it would be very helpful as well.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include the keyword _Chart_ between _ChartObjects_ and _FullSeriesCollection_: `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Leb!$C$2:$G$2"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there...

```
With Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Leb!$C$2:$G$2"
End With
```

`XValues` belongs to a `Series` object, not the Chart (referring to your last code sample).

EDIT:

```
Dim arrCharts, cht
arrCharts = Array("Chart 3", "Chart 4", "Chart 5", "Chart 7")

For Each cht In arrCharts
    With Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects(cht).Chart
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Leb!$C$2:$G$2"
    End With
Next cht
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to make this exact change to multiple charts on the same sheet? I tried `With Worksheets("Dash Board").ChartObjects("Chart 3", "Chart 4", "Chart 5", "Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Leb!$C$2:$G$2"End With`

Comment: @TimWilliams You mean `SeriesCollection` belongs to a `Chart`, not to the `ChartObject`

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks again! I had to change the 2nd "End With" to "Next cht", but it works perfectly now :)